# How can i stop a rotate with animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I've tried some animations but I don't find any solution. I've shared with you a video about my animation below.

I get this following animation with rotation. How can I make the animation stop by slowing down when I say stop?

[animation video link](https://vimeo.com/769217615)

I've tried this code

```
    func stopRotate() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        })
    }
```

my rotate animation code

```
func rotate() {
        let rotation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotation.toValue = Double.pi * 2
        rotation.duration = 0.75 // or however long you want ...
        rotation.isCumulative = true
        rotation.repeatCount = 15
        self.layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }
```